# How to know if no object has focus?

Tags: javascript

How do I find out if no object has focus?

Example scenario: The page reloads and I run a function which will say if any object has focus or no one has it.

Just asking here because google didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`document.activeElement`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#dom-document-activeelement) to get the current element in focus.

Note that you shouldn't need to do this. If a page reloads you can default focus to a specific element using the [autofocus attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control)

Comment: @jAndy your IE7 doesn't get the javascript because the mimetype is `"application/javascript"`. Thankfully the HTML only page works. Enjoy your HTML experience.

Comment: @jAndy IE7 support, happy now?

Comment: I'm trying `autofocus` but doesn't works. I search about it and found that it's a `HTML5` attribute and doesn't work on IE !! And `activeElement` throws an error.

Comment: @Márcio of course it doesn't work on IE !!. Nothing works on IE. Welcome to web development. [Maybe google for "autofocus shim"](https://gist.github.com/1119343)

Comment: So what is this, Oh Almighty Lord of Knowledge [Error](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/221/errorwd.png/) ?!?!

Comment: @Márcio who knows, I don't speak spanish

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery you can do:

```
var focusedElements = $('*:focus');
```

and then check the length of this variable.

```
if ( $('*:focus').length > 0)
    // Some object has focus!
else
    // No focus
```

http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

Comment: Dear god that sounds horribly inefficient

Comment: I give priority to answers without jquery, but if I can't do without it, I'll have to try this. Thank you.

Comment: @Raynos: it is horribly inefficient, this code will imply a query for every single node wihin the markup.

Comment: @jAndy not really, sizzle uses `document.activeElement` with the `:focus` selector.

Comment: @Raynos: didn't know that sizzle checks explicitly for that. So it'll ignore the universal selector in that case entirely?

Comment: @jAndy Actually it might still walk the entire tree, depends how stupid sizzle is.

Answer (score -1):

You could add an event on every item to get a class "hasFocus", onFocus. Then you know which element got the current focus. Of course you also need to remove this class in an onblur event.

Comment: This approach might work but is it realistic?  What if there are dozens, or even hundreds, of items?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I thought that too

Comment: You are right. I didn't knew that `$('*:focus')` is possible.

Comment: You don't need -1 for this, people have no patience.